How is it known that the stars move in the universe because spacetime is expanding and not that the stars expand through empty space?
Quoting one article,

This expansion should not be thought of as stars flying away from each
other in a static spacetime fabric. Instead, the stars are more or
less static relative to a spacetime fabric that is itself expanding.

How long before the expansion of the universe causes our earth to drift away from the sun?
I've read this concept hundreds of times but I never seen the argument that proves it.
How is it known that the stars move in the universe because spacetime is expanding and not that the stars expand through empty space?
